# Django ORM: how to cast geometry to geography in filter?

Tags: python, django, postgis, geodjango

In my Django project, I have defined a `geometry` field on one of my model. Its SRID is 4326 (WGS 84).

I would like to write with Django ORM a query that will translate to:

```sql
select * from building
where
    (ST_DWITHIN(shape::geography,
    ST_MakePoint(1.9217,47.8814)::geography,20))
```

In other words, I would like to filter the queryset using the `ST_DWITHIN` function, applied to a geometry field (shape) casted to a geography.

The only way I could find is to use the `extra()` function, like so:

```py
Building.objects.extra(
where=[
  f"ST_DWITHIN(shape::geography, ST_MakePoint({lng}, {lat})::geography, {radius})"
])
```

But the `extra` function is supposed to be deprecated in future version of Django, according to the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra).

Can I write this query without escaping from the ORM?

Maybe using the [Cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) function ?